# Read input Values and Display In DIV or Textarea Randomly

Tags: jquery, random, user-input

http://liveweave.com/SmxRe1

What I'm trying to do is take the value if the inputs and randomly display it in a textarea. When I insert say "100" in the input textbox's it shows a random number below 100. I'm trying to just take the inputs and randomly show the input values in the textbox. I thought I knew what to do but evidently I don't otherwise I wouldn't be posting here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Value Test Generation</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' charset='utf-8' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#genbtn').click(GenRandomInput);

    function GenRandomInput() {
        var txtval = $("input[name='textbox1']").val();
        var txtvals = $("input.textbox").val();
        var testrandomnuminputs = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
        var randinputs = Math.floor(Math.random() * txtvals);

        $('#raninputs').val(randinputs);

  return false;}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div><label>Truth #1</label><input type="text" name="textbox1" class="textbox" value="One" /></div>

    <div><label>Truth #2</label><input type="text" name="textbox2" class="textbox" value="Two" /></div>

    <div><label>Truth #3</label><input type="text" name="textbox3" class="textbox" value="Three" /></div>

    <div><label>Truth #4</label><input type="text" name="textbox4" class="textbox" value="Four" /></div>

    <input type="button" id="genbtn" value="Start">

    <div class="genarea">
        <textarea id="raninputs" placeholder="Random inputs generate here"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so let me understand this correctly ... #raninputs should display the 4 truths in random order?

Comment: Math.random will output a number like this 0.239481094, using Math.floor it becomes always 0

Comment: Not clear still what you want. Is it numbers or text in the inputs?

Comment: Yes, and Primarily Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for text, to randomly show one of the input fields try this:

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x9QMP/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('#genbtn').click(GenRandomInput);
    function GenRandomInput() {
        var txtvals = $("input.textbox").length;
        var testrandomnuminputs = Math.floor(Math.random() * txtvals)
        var randinputs = $("input")[testrandomnuminputs].value;
        $('#raninputs').val(randinputs);
  return false;}
});
```